# how to open file in /Android/data with other App?

Tags: android, saf

After Android 11, we can't access the **Android/data** directory directly using File I/O. By using **SAF**, I can now use DocumentFile to traverse the file I want, but when I want to open the file with another app, I find I can't do it. Even if I pass in the correct Uri parameter, the other app can't access the file because it doesn't have permission, which I can understand. But I found an app called "MT Manager" and I was surprised to find that it can open files in any folder in the data directory and use other third-party apps, which is amazing and I can't understand it at all.
Please help, do you know what to do?

```
fun Context.openFile(uri: Uri) {
    try {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, MapTable.getMIMEType(uri.toString()))
        this.startActivity(intent)
        Intent.createChooser(intent, "choose app")
    } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "sorry cannot open it！", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

This code is valid for files in the normal directory, but not in the ***Android/data*** directory after Android 11.

this is which i find [MT Manager](https://www.coolapk.com/apk/bin.mt.plus)

I can think of a not very clever method, which is to copy the files in the sdcard/Android/data directory to the sdcard directory, and then call the above method. This works, but it is not good enough. I don’t know what it is. How to achieve it, his effect looks very good.

```
val extract = {
                ctx.toast("please wait...")
                val target = File(ROOT_DIR + fileModel.name)
                GlobalThreadPools.getInstance().execute {
                    fileModel.documentFile?.let { doc ->
                        val fis = ctx.contentResolver.openInputStream(doc.uri)
                        fis?.let { `is` ->
                            val bis = BufferedInputStream(`is`)
                            val fos = FileOutputStream(target)
                            try {
                                val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
                                var len: Int
                                while (((bis.read(buffer)).also { len = it }) != -1) {
                                    fos.write(buffer, 0, len)
                                }
                                Thread.sleep(100)
                                postUI {
                                    ctx.openFile(target.path)
                                }
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                postUI {
                                    ctx.toast("faild！")
                                }
                            } finally {
                                fos.close()
                                bis.close()
                                `is`.close()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You can no more access the `Android/data` folder. You'll probably need `All Files Access` permission granted for the same on SDK >= 31. `MT Manager` might be using targetSdk < 31 & have `requestLegacyExternalStorage` flag.

Comment: @DarShan Yes, that app TargetSdkVersion of this application is 26, but this is not the point, because even if I lower the TargetSdkVersion, I still can't achieve his effect. Maybe you want to try [MT Manager](https://www.coolapk.com/apk/bin.mt.plus)

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag grant read uri permission